# ORA-01722: invalid number, SQL in clause

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
$query = "delete from document where document_lientype =:lienType and document_lienid =:lienId and document_id not in (:docsIds)";
$params = array(
    'lienType' => $lienType,
    'lienId'   => $lienId,
    'docsIds'  => implode(',',$docsIds)
);
```

When I dump `$docsIds` I get:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(19357)
  [1] =>
  int(19358)
  [2] =>
  int(19378)
}
```

And when I dump `implode(',',$docsIds)` I get:

```
string(17) "19357,19358,19378"
```

When I run the query in my project I get the error `ORA-01722: invalid number` which means it is not being able to convert the `docsIds` into integers.

When I run the query in TOAD, it executes correctly; so the problem is coming from that `in` clause.

I tried to construct the string in all the ways I could imagine of, including: `"'19357','19358','19378'"` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't bind a list of values like that in a single bind. You need to have a separate placeholder for each value in the list. So you would probably want to build your query in a loop so you end up with `in (:docId1,:docId2,:docId3)`...etc. with a separate placeholder for each `docId`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn ahh now I get it. thank you 

Comment: I didn't make that an answer because I wasn't sure if there was a better method, but since no one else has responded, I'll write it up in a little bit with an example.